# Slickgrid, how to get the grid item on click event?

Tags: slickgrid

```
grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e) {
    var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(e),
        row = cell.row;

    // var item = dataView.rows[row];

});
```

I used to use dataView.rows to access the item inside a grid, and this seems not working in the latest version any more, how shall we update the code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e, args) {
  var item = args.item;

  // or dataView.getItem(args.row);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

This gets me to the object itself:

```
grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e, args) {
           console.log('clicked: ');
           console.log(args);
           var item = args.grid.getData()[args.row];
           console.log(item);

         });
```

Comment: I like this the best. Or rather args.grid.getDataItem(args.row);   Is it possible to update the dataView through args in any way?  I don't have access to any global var for dataView within this scope.

Answer (score 5):

This is quite an old thread, still I felt to update it since args no longer has 'item' in it.

Now it is:

```
grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    var cell = args.cell,
    row = args.row;
});
```

Comment: This returns the # of the cell you clicked